# Customizable options not showing in cart or order

Tags: magento2.2.2, customizable-options

Magento 2.2.2, when an item is added to the cart, any customizable options selected when adding a product to the cart are not displayed in the cart or order.

In testing, I have found that the Sku that is passed to CheckoutCartProdtuctAdd does not contain the part of the SKU specified in the customizable option.

I have a backup from a month ago that does pass the Sku correctly, I have compared files and tested and found that the problem is caused by an entry in the database i.e. if I get the working backup and run it up with its database it works, but if I run it with a copy of the database from the current non-working site the problem is there.

I am sorry I cannot give steps to recreate as I don't know when this happened or what caused it.

Any help deeply appreciated as I am tearing my hair out!

Many thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

The problem was:
I had overwritten Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\details.phtml, in the file, I had some temporary code that was making some attribute value changes to the configurable and it's children and saving them both.

Calling $product->save() on the configurable product, in this case, caused has_options and required_options in the database table catalog_product_entity to be set to 0 regardless of whether the product has options or not.

I removed the line that saved the configurable product, then reset has_options and required_options to 1 for all configurable products that had options to stop the problem recurring.